# android- How to make a dialog opens under actionbar

Tags: android, android-dialog

I don't know if I can say it properly .
I saw it in another application, when the user clicks on search button on actionbar , a dialog opens under actionbar and we can close it by holding finger at the bottom and drag it up.

[image]

How can I make something like this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to use **PopopWindow**:

```
public void showMenu(){

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);

    // Create some group view to show up
    GroupView view = ....

    // set some pupup window properties
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupWindow.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // set your group view as a popup window content
    popupWindow.setContentView(view);

    // This will allow you to close window by clickin not in its area
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    // Show the window at desired place. The first argument is a control, wich will be used to place window... defining dx and dy will shift the popup window
    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(controlToShowAt, dx, dy);
}
```

Hope this will help.